# How i can receive variable from another thread in Jmeter

Tags: java, ruby, jmeter

in the first thread, I received JSON (format - **{"id":6054,"name":"Jmeter created chat","description":"jmeter created test"}**)

I want to use it in the second thread variable '6054'

I use BeanShell Assertion with code:
`${__setProperty(("id":"(.+?)"), ${chat_id)};`

but it, of course, doesn't work, please tell me the right way..

many thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. It won't work because your [__setProperty()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) function call doesn't make sense at all and it's syntactically incorrect
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

So

1. Remove your Beanshell Assertion
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above response
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   props.put('chat_id', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).id as String)
   ```
4. In 2nd Thread Group access the value using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as:

   ```
   ${__P(chat_id,)}
   ```

Demo:

[image]

More information regarding what these `prev` and `props` guys mean can be found in the [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy article](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

---

P.S. You may find [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-inter-thread-communication-plugin-in-jmeter) easier to use